# How to undo last transactions in Django DB

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

Well, I've a data in a csv file which is to be inserted in the DB. Now I cannot guarantee that the data provided will be according to my needs, so I want if there is any exception, then the previous transactions on the DB should be undo.

What I currently do is that the data is saved till an exception is found. I throw the exception and then prints the exception at the line number. What I want is that the whole file should be inserted again without any duplicate rows. How can I do it?

Here is my code:-

```
for row in rows:
    line += 1
    try : 
        obj = XYZ(col1 = row[0],col2=row[1])
        obj.save()
    except : raise ("Excetion found at line ", line)
```

How should I undo all the previous transactions which were done before an exception arised??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is [`atomic()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic), to quote the docs (emphasis mine):

> Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. atomic
>   allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the
>   database is guaranteed. **If the block of code is successfully
>   completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an
>   exception, the changes are rolled back.**

Comment: So, if any DB transaction throws error(exception), all previous will be rolled back, even if I dont catch those errors ?

Comment: @user1162512 yes. Also, note that the docs specifically mention that you shouldn't catch exceptions *inside* the atomic block, but rather *around* it (I would've shown you here, but the docs are so very detailed there's just no need)